# How to debug "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference error"

Tags: reference, group-by, outer-join

Since SSRS doesn't allow filters on aggregates, I found some code which helped me come up with the below query.  However, when I run it I get:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

I have searched everywhere but can't find how to fix this. I've even removed the two extra tables from the query so there were no joins at all.  I need to not return any order where the total of the lines on the order is less than $500 and greater than 0.

```
SELECT 
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines.company, 
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines.order_number,  
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines.amount, 
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines.item, 
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines.container
FROM
  tdsls041_sales_order_lines AS tdsls041_sales_order_lines 
WHERE
 (tdsls041_sales_order_lines.company = 610)  AND 
 (tdsls041_sales_order_lines.order_number IN
 (SELECT
    tdsls041_sales_order_lines.order_number
  FROM            
    tdsls041_sales_order_lines AS tdsls041_sales_order_lines_1
  GROUP BY 
    tdsls041_sales_order_lines.order_number
  HAVING  
    (SUM(tdsls041_sales_order_lines.amount) <= 500) OR
     SUM(tdsls041_sales_order_lines.amount) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that SQL Server is complaining about is that the **Grouping** wants an aggregate function in the SELECT statement. Unfortunately, you want to use **IN** which you need a list of **Order Numbers**.

You just need to add an aggregate function to your subquery and then add another layer to select just the Order Numbers from that.

```
SELECT T1.company, T1.order_number,  T1.amount, T1.item, T1.container
FROM    tdsls041_sales_order_lines AS T1  
WHERE   (T1.company = 610) AND (T1.order_number IN
                    (SELECT order_number FROM 
                             (SELECT        TSOL.order_number, SUM(TSOL.amount) AS TTL
                               FROM            tdsls041_sales_order_lines AS TSOL
                               GROUP BY TSOL.order_number
                               HAVING (SUM(TSOL.amount) <= 500) OR
                                                   SUM(TSOL.amount) > 0) AS T2) )
```

You can filter on aggreagates in Chart and Tables. You have to put the aggregate filter on your GROUP instead of on the table itself (Group Properties->Filters tab).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I try that, it gave me an error also.  It says Each group by expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference still but then it also says only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with exists.

Comment: I changed the IN to EXISTS and I still get the outer reference error.

Comment: I missed the fact that the subquery changed when I ran it so I fixed that part and the query does run with no errors now.  However, it doesn't filter out what I need it to.  I'm getting orders that are over $500.  Here is my where clause now.

Comment: It did change my Having statement to

Comment: HAVING         (SUM(amount) <= 500) OR
                                                                                   (SUM(amount) > 0)) AS derivedtbl_1))

Comment: Although it would be nice to know how to do that query, I just saw your comment that you can filter on the group, which I did and it worked.  Thanks for your help.  That did work.

Comment: Glad it worked. It looks like I forgot to Alias the second table. I have updated the query for future reference.